# ¿Por qué una "gruesa" son "doce docenas"?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, español-neutral

[**Gruesa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ja0Q4FQ) tiene la acepción

> 10. f. Número de doce docenas, especialmente de cosas menudas. *Una gruesa de botones, de agujas.*

Que no parece tener mucha relación con las restantes acepciones. ¿Cómo surgió?

EDICION
En "Asterix y el Caldero" se define una gruesa como **catorce catorcenas**  <sup>[2](http://diccionarioasterix.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/g.html)</sup>; siempre pensé que era una broma, pero veo que *catorcena* si figura en el diccionario de la lengua <sup>[3](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7ycSVpl)</sup>.

Comment: @walen: Creía que debo aceptar la respuesta que me parece correcta, por lo que si después de aceptar una hay otra que me parece mejor, debo cambiarlo. Y si una tercera me plantea dudas, que quizás sea mejor esperar algo más de tiempo, para ver si surgen otras respuestas o matizaciones mejores. Ahora creo entenderte que no se debe hacer, y eso me deja confuso.

Answer (score 4):

In Mediaeval Latin the word *grossus* meant great or big and is supposedly the source for the Spanish *grueso*. In Old French a *grosse douzaine* was a large dozen and hence a gross in the sense of 144. This [page](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gross) (in English) discusses the etymology of the English word gross but is I think relevant to the Spanish since we are both deriving the word from Latin.

Comment: Woudn't a 'large dozen' be something bigger than a dozen (like *the baker's dozen*, *la docena del fraile*) and not necessarily **twelve dozens**?

Comment: That would be logical but language is not always logical I am afraid.

Answer (score 4):

Pues no creas que es tan sencillo encontrar el origen...

Buscando en el [NTTLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUISalirNtlle), vemos que la palabra **"gruessa"** con la acepción de "doce docenas" aparecía ya en la primera edición del diccionario de Autoridades, en 1734:

[image]

Eso quiere decir que el origen es seguramente anterior al siglo XVIII. Y por anterior, estamos hablando de cualquiera de los diez siglos previos.

Nos vamos entonces al [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) para buscar apariciones de la palabra en textos de esos siglos. Podemos encontrar usos con ese sentido en el s. XVI:

> 17 Agugetas de hilo á cien maravedís la **gruesa** que es doce docenas... 100 Agallas á dos mil quinientos maravedís el quintal... 2, 500
>   <sub>Anónimo, *Valuación hecha en la villa de Bilbao del precio de las mercaderías que venían de fuera del Reino*, **1563**.</sub>

E incluso en el s. XV:

> cucharas
>   - Primeramente, **una gruesa** de cucharas pyntadas de foja de peral, a veynte e syete maravedís, e por dosena a tres maravedís.
>   - otrosy, **la gruesa** de las cucharas, llanas, blancas, a dies e ocho maravedís, e por dosena a dos maravedís.
>   <sub>Anónimo, *Arancel de precios y salarios de Cuenca*, **1462**.</sub>

Pero no he hallado nada más antiguo que eso.

En [este foro](http://z13.invisionfree.com/DozensOnline/ar/t245.htm) hay una discusion sobre el origen de la palabra inglesa *gross*, que significa lo mismo; y comentan lo siguiente:

> *My old 'Complete Oxford English dictionary' for 'gross = twleve dozen'
>   refers to French 'grosse', Spanish 'grueso', Italian 'grossa', as the
>   feminine of a word meaning 'big'. It says that the Vulgate has 'grossus'
>   as the adjective for 'big'.*

Y también:

> *The obvious backformation is* (duodecena) grossa, *but the fact is the Romans didn't use a word for 'dozen', let alone higher duodecimal powers, for the simple reason they didn't count integers by the dozen. They did have a pretty extensive set of names for duodecimal (and related) subdivisions, though; since they did use twelfths for fractions, especially for subdividing measurement and monetary units. The Romans were practical-minded people, and grouping items into ten-based collectives such as the hundred and the thousand is practical for counting them on fingers, while splitting stuff into twelve-based subdivisions is useful for commerce.*

Resumiendo, vienen a decir que la misma palabra existe tanto en inglés, como en italiano, francés o español, y en todas con el mismo significado de "doce docenas"; pero que este significado no puede venir del latín, porque los romanos usaban un sistema de numeración decimal, no duodecimal. En latín, "grossus" significaba "grande", punto. Eso de las docenas se usaba solo en comercio.

Nótese que los únicos usos que hemos encontrado son, efectivamente, en textos comerciales; nadie decía "atacaron con una *gruesa* de hombres", sino "atacaron con *doze dozenas* de hombres".

Con todo lo anterior (y esto es una conjetura mía), **lo más probable es que "*gruesa*" con el significado de "doce docenas" fuese una palabra tomada del [sabir](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabir)**, la [*lingua franca*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lengua_vehicular) usada por los marineros y comerciantes europeos entre los siglos XIV y XIX para entenderse entre ellos.

Comment: La explicación general bien, pero el último párrafo te ha quedado un poco _deux ex machina_. De repente y sin venir a cuento te sacas de la manga lo del *sabir*. ¿Cómo has llegado a esa conclusión? ¿Podrías explicarla un poco más?

Comment: Hay un largo trecho entre los romanos y el siglo XV español. El foro que citas menciona que la palabra *docena* viene del francés antiguo (ss. VIII-XIV) por presunta derivación analógica a la de *decena*, y de ahí puede venir también la "gruesa" (*grosse dozeine*) y todos sus cognados en otras lenguas.

Comment: @walen Me refería a que el comentario del foro implicaba que la "docena grande" no podía venir del latín porque los romanos no usaban la docena, lo cual es interesante sólo de manera negativa (elimina el latín como posible origen del término). En medio hay mil años de evolución del latín vulgar y el romance donde pudo surgir y propagarse el término. Esto no es una crítica a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Ciertamente, las palabras *gruesa* del español y *gross* del inglés debían tener el mismo origen al significar lo mismo. Como bien apunta mdewey [en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22284/12637), la palabra parece provenir del francés *grosse douzaine* ("gran docena"), aunque traduciendo (tal vez erróneamente) *grosse* por *gruesa*.

En la etimología enlazada por mdewey se dice que el origen fue a principios del siglo XV. Esto cuadra con la primera aparición de la expresión en el CORDE, que es la siguiente:

> - *Primeramente, una gruesa de cucharas pyntadas de foja de peral, a veynte e syete maravedís, e por dosena a tres maravedís.*
> - *otrosy, la gruesa de las cucharas, llanas, blancas, a dies e ocho maravedís, e por dosena a dos maravedís.*
>
> Anónimo, "Arancel de precios y salarios de Cuenca" (Documentos sobre industria textil), 1462 (España).

Queda claro que el documento habla de los precios por docena de ciertos objetos (la docena era una unidad muy usada para vender artículos), y de los descuentos aplicados por volumen (si te llevas una gruesa te cobran 9 docenas en vez de 12).